# Java Exception name

Tags: java, swing, exception, jframe

Posted below is my current code.....it is a Jframe, and is used to calculate a user's ideal weight based off their BMI. I currently have a try,catch to test for a NumberFormatException, when the user enters invalid data, but I would also like to test for another thing. What I want is: when the user enters NO data in the input areas, it throws another error. I don't know the name of such an exception, or even if one exists.

```java
 private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // string declaration
    String measurementSystem;
    String name;
    double height;
    double outputweight;

    // clears the output box for the next entry
    outputField.setText("");

    try {

        // variable definition, also creates
        // decimal format for rounding
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#.##");
        name = inputnameField.getText();
        height = Double.parseDouble(inputheightField.getText());
        measurementSystem = inputmeasureField.getText();

        // checks for a value in measurementSystem,
        // if equal to M or I (ignoring case),
        // it will run either code.
        // if neither, it tells the user to input a valid value,
        // and resets the measure input box for them.
        if ("M".equalsIgnoreCase(measurementSystem)) {
            outputweight = height * height * 25;
            outputField.setText(name + "'s ideal weight is " + df.format(outputweight) + " kgs.");
            inputheightField.setText("");
            inputmeasureField.setText("");
            inputnameField.setText("");
        }
        else if ("I".equalsIgnoreCase(measurementSystem)) {
            outputweight = height * height * 25 / 703;
            outputField.setText(name + "'s ideal weight is " + df.format(outputweight) + " lbs.");
            inputheightField.setText("");
            inputmeasureField.setText("");
            inputnameField.setText("");
        }
        else {
            outputField.setText("Please input a valid measure system.");
            inputmeasureField.setText("");
        } 
    }

    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        outputField.setText("Please input valid numbers.");
        inputheightField.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always create a custom exception class and have it extend the closest related exception class.

Comment: I am not aware of any exception that expresses that. You can try a `IllegalArgumentException`, which seems too broad, or just create your own.

Comment: There's no need for an exception to do that. Just use an `if` statement: `if (name.isEmpty()) { // display error message }`

Comment: @JBNizet When I put your suggestion at the bottom of the code, it gives the error " 'void' type not allowed here." ? ( however you have been the only person who's answer I can understand so far, so thanks!)

Comment: I can't explain an error without seeing the code causing that error. This shouldn't be "at the bottom of the code". It should be where you want to test the emptiness of the field: before trying to parse it as a double.